# Is there a process that would allow a question to be "migrated" and still exist open on both original and target site?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

I was searching for some information relative to a possible SharePoint bug when google search reported me this two links:

SharePoint SE: [How do you remove fields from a custom list in SharePoint that have been added via the 'Add from existing site columns' menu item?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248/how-do-you-remove-fields-from-a-custom-list-in-sharepoint-that-have-been-added-v)

SO : [How do you remove/delete a column in a custom list that you added from existing site columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560928/how-do-you-remove-delete-a-column-in-a-custom-list-that-you-added-from-existing)

As you can see the title are pretty similar... but that is only the start.
If we open the questions, we can see that the contents are pretty similar to. Same user posting same question, some of the answers are the same too (and from the same users).

Considering also some of the answer. One in particular seem to be the same answer on both sites, posted almost at the same time (3 minutes difference) and from the same **unregistered** user on both sites. This really caught my eye as strange.

I can't explain this. The post times seem to indicate some sort of migration process - was it a sockpuppet attempt I would expect them to differ more. Yet, the question also present some difference that aren't documented from edits in their history.

I have a theory: the question was migrated at a database level, probably to give the SharePoint site a starting set of contents when the site was still young in order to promote grow. Is this reasonable? <strike>What other explanation could this have?</strike> I am not really interested in *this* specific case - this was only an example to give context-, what I am really wondering is if *there are case of "migrated/crossposted" contents done with tools that do not leave a track of the post begin actually originated from a copy process.*

I have tried to ask for opinion in the meta Tavern chat room, but most of the other users where pretty stumped too.

---

**EDIT**:

Having reviewed the data from Rene, I can assume that this is *probably* just a strange case of crosspost. 
My question still remain the same: can a site receive a "copy" of a question in some case while the original one remains in the open? Was such behaviour even used to "start up" new sites with content taken from partially overlapping older sites? Could in that way SharePoint be a special case since it both was migrated from a SE 1.0 site and overlaps with SO?

Comment: I guess this is peculiar to SharePoint, which is an imported SE 1.0 site.

Comment: [SEDE PostHistory for SP.se](http://data.stackexchange.com/sharepoint/query/305433) and [Post history for SO](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305436)

Comment: Tavern only has bots, no users to speak of/to

Comment: Yeah, we are all bots. Bleep!

Comment: @user147263 probably, that was why I asked. The question has too many strange characteristic that seem to indicate it wasn't just a case of socks or crosspost.

Comment: @rene thanks for the data, have had some time to review them and update the question as needed

Comment: Check them dates http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1/sharepoint-overflow-joins-the-stack-exchange-2-0-family

Comment: Look, when writing the answer I forgot about some mod-only feature :) your upvote reminded me about it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's possible.

When the question is migrated, it's left locked on the parent site (until deleted, which is not done immediately, and you always can get to it by appending `?noredirect=true` to the original url) and appears on the both sites.

Then, a mod can just use "clear migration history" in the mod menu and everything regarding migration on the parent site is cleared.